# How can I connect to my Airport Extreme Shared Disk using Windows?

Tags: macos, windows-xp, router, airport

I have a shared disk attached to my Airport Extreme, which I can connect to remotely in OS X through the finder via command - k, and entering in the proper address:

```
afp://test.dyndns.org:1111
```

1111 being the port I've reserved for the disk in the AE port mapping.

This is such a great feature, but I don't always have access to a Mac.

My question is how can I connect to this drive via Windows XP?

Please note, that the shared drive is a Drobo FS and formatted to handle both Windows and Mac OS.

I've tried mapping a network drive via My Computer -> Tools -> Map Network Drive and entering:

```
\\test.dyndns.org:1111\Drobo-Name
```

I've also tried Start -> Run and entering the same, both with and without the port #.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a Drobo FS has an Ethernet jack and simply plugs into any Ethernet network, and acts as its own AFP and SMB server (Mac and Windows file sharing, respectively), right?

Since it's not a USB disk, it's not what most people would call an AirPort Extreme shared disk" -- that term usually refers to a USB disk plugged into an AirPort Extreme, for which the AirPort Extreme Base Station acts as the AFP and SMB server.

It sounds like you've got a port mapping from your AirPort Extreme's public IP address, port 1111, to the Drobo FS's private IP address, port 548 (the standard AFP server port). Is that correct?

If you want Windows clients to be able to get to the Drobo FS the same way, you need to make similar port mappings for the ports that SMB and related protocols use to connect to servers. See this article at sister site ServerFault.com: https://serverfault.com/questions/36100/port-forwarding-for-samba

Also note that some of those SMB- and NetBIOS-related ports are some of the most-attacked ports on the internet, second only perhaps to the SSH port (21).  Because of that's, it's not uncommon for residential broadband ISPs to filter those ports by default.  So even if you got your NAT port mapping set up perfectly, you still might not be able to connect in from the outside, because your ISP might be blocking it "for your own good".